# Restangular: Waiting for resolve of promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular

I'm new to Javascript and AngularJS and this one makes me scratch my head :/

**Precondition**

- A REST Service providing my data from the backend
- AngularJS 1.2.21 and Restangular 1.4.0
- An AngularJS controller, that shall ask the service for a spiced up version of the provided

**What I have**

This is the method in question:

```
   service.getSlices = function() {

        Restangular.all('entries').getList().then(function(entries) {

            //some rather complex modification of the backend data go here
            //...

            return  resultOfModification; //this is what should be returned for getSlices();
        })

        //I want the resultOfModification to be returned here


    };
```

**The question**

Bascially I would like to wait in `getSlices()` until the promise is resolved in order to return my `resultOfModification` only when it actually is calculated.

*Additional scenario*
I could also image to return a promise from `getSlices()` which would then provide the `resultOfModification`. However I fear I do not understand this well enough and / or am too frustrated / tired meanwhile.

Answers and any suggestions are welcome, especially pointers to good reading material. Thanks

Comment: You can't return it at that place as actual value, because `Restangular` is async ( `getSlices` is left before the `then` callback is called).  That's why `Promise` is used. So the _correct_ way would be to return the Promise and do: `service.getSlices().then(function(resultOfModification) { });`?

Comment: I already imaged this might not be feasible from what I read so far, although I hoped there might be some way to break from that asynchrony. How would I make `getSlices()` return a promise that will contain my `resultOfModification`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't return it at that place as actual value, because `Restangular` is async (the function `getSlices` is left before the  callback you pass to `then` is called). That's why `Promise` is used.

Even if it would be possible to make `Restangular` to be sync you shouldn't do that because this will block the browser until the data is requested which will be a bad user experience.

You should try to get into `Promise` as they where designed to look like sync code but behave async.

The thing you would need to change in your code is to add a `return` before the `Restangular.all` :

```
  service.getSlices = function() {
      return Restangular.all('entries').getList().then(function(entries) {

          //some rather complex modification of the backend data go here
          //...

          return  resultOfModification; //this is what should be returned for getSlices();
      })
  };
```

This will return the `Promise` that is return by the `.then` call. This Promise will resolve to `resultOfModification` as this is the vale you return form its callback.

That way you could use `getSlices`  that way:

```
  service.getSlices().then(function(modifiedData) {

  });
```

---

Promises can be chained up:

```
  (new Promise(function( resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("some");
    },200);
  }))
  .then(function(data) {
    return data+' data';
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    //here a Promise is return which will resovle later (cause of the timeout)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(data+' !!!!!!');
      },200);
    });
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    //this will have 'some data !!!!!!'
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Which would be the same as if you would write it that way:

```
  var promiseA = new Promise(function( resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("some");
    },200);
  });

  var promiseB = promiseA.then(function(data) {
    return data+' data';
  })


  var promiseC = promiseB.then(function(data) {
    //here a Promise is return which will resovle later (cause of the timeout)
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(data+' !!!!!!');
      },200);
    });
  });

  var promiseD = promiseC.then(function(data) {
    //this will have 'some data !!!!!!'
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: This sounds great. I'm all eager to try out once I come back to work. Thanks so far!

Comment: works perferctly! Your explanation of chaining promises was most helpful:D